# My form keeps sending the information to my Junk email

Tags: php, forms

I have a form on my page and the information I submit keeps going to my junk folder within my Hotmail email.

I'm not sure what to do I keep changing the headers but the mail still keeps coming into my junk folder.

The code for the PHP is:

```
    <?php
$boundary = uniqid('np');

$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'user@hotmail.co.uk';


$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP's mail() Function\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Subject: Contact\r\n";


$message = "This is a MIME encoded message."; 

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $message .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= "This is the text/plain version.";

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
 $message .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
 $message .= "This is the <b>text/html</b> version.";

 $message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";



$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. I will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'http://www.user.com';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to user@hotmail.co.uk');
        window.location = 'url';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem is if the smtp server from which you are sending the emails, doesn't match the "from" email.

For example if you fill the from field with "yourmail@gmail.com" and the smtp server is not the gmail's one, this might be marked as spam by some mail providers. Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do about it, besides from sending emails from your own domain, that resolves to your smtp server.